# What is the history of the term "metasyntactic variable"?

Tags: etymology, nonce-words

#### Background

A **metasyntactic variable** is a word or term that stands in for something else, typically used when you're describing an overall pattern, and the subject under discussion could have any name in actual practice. A placeholder.

It's most commonly used in computer science and related fields, and in that community *foo* is the most commonly used and recognized metasyntactic variable.

#### Example

The classic example from [the C2 Wiki](http://wiki.c2.com/?MetasyntacticVariable):

> Suppose I have a list, foo, with a node, bar, ...

What this allows us to do is now refer to the list as "foo" and and the node as "bar", as in "now, if bar is the last node in foo...", while recognizing that in a program the *real* "foo" and "bar" could have any name at all.

#### Origins

But here, I'm not asking about "foo" or "bar"¹ or any specific metasyntactic variable, I'm asking about the term *metasyntactic variable*.

A [recent answer on a different question](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/375592/55623) suggested the author Terry Pratchett could have invented it:

> Terry Pratchett .. used the idea of a 'Metasyntactic variable' (his own nomenclature I believe but open to correction).

Pratchett didn't invent the term, but the answer prompted me to look into who did, and I'm stumped.

So:

1. When was the term *metasyntactic variable* first used, or *metasyntactic* modifying some other word, giving the same meaning?
2. Why *meta*-syntactic?
3. Was there any specific event or author who popularized it, or was its growth simply organic?
4. Is the term used with the same meaning in any interesting ways outside of the software world (like the Terry Pratchett example)?

#### Early uses

Using Google Books and Google nGrams², the earliest use of the full term *metasyntactic variable* I could find was the 1979 work
[*The MDL Programming Language*](https://books.google.com/books?id=u9BWAAAAMAAJ&q=%22metasyntactic%20variable%22&dq=%22metasyntactic%20variable%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjz1aKXi67SAhUk0YMKHZsdBtw4KBDoAQgjMAI), which reads, on page 4:

> A **metasyntactic variable** -- something to be replaced in actual use by something else -- appears as a *radix:fix*, in an italic font; often the variable will have both a meaning and a data type (as here), but sometimes those will be omitted, for obvious reasons.

and on page 44:

> TYPE (aren't homonyms wonderful?), just type the appropriate ATOM, like FIX or FLOAT or ATOM etc. However, in this document we will use the convention that a **metasyntactic variable** can have a *type* for a "data type": for example, foo:type means that the TYPE of *foo* is ATOM, but the ATOM must be something that the SUBR TYPE can return.

These paragraphs suggest, respectively, that (a) the term is *new* enough that it has to be defined (a 1990 [Emacs Lisp manual](https://books.google.com/books?id=f3MeAQAAIAAJ&q=%22metasyntactic%22%20%22variable%22&dq=%22metasyntactic%22%20%22variable%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiYjprEl67SAhUJ0mMKHdpNBF44MhDoAQgkMAI) uses the word unselfconsicously and without any definition, because by then everyone knew what it meant), and (b) that it's *established* enough that the authors have to defend their novel convention that m.v.s may have data types (which is atypical).

Which means this may be an early use, but not the first use.

So, broadening my search, and looking for only *metasyntactic*, I found [ALGOL-Bulletin no. 13](http://archive.computerhistory.org/resources/text/algol/ACM_Algol_bulletin/1060935/p1-naur.pdf), published August 1961, mentioning a memo written in  November 1960 which used that word:

[image: Serial no. 10. From Peter Zilahy Ingerman and Kirk Sattley. 7.11.60. Subject: Proposed symbols for use in ALGOL translators. The authors give a list of letter combinations, corresponding to all basic symbols and metasyntactic classes of ALGOL 60, for use in describing ALGOL translators.]

But it's not clear whether this *metasyntactic* had the same sense as it does in the full term *metasyntactic variable*, as the word "classes" suggest this might be a more specific and technical term of art in ALGOL's design, or computer language design more broadly.

#### "Meta" syntactic

Aside from its first use, I'm interested in why the term "metasyntactic" was chosen in the first place.  What is "meta" about these terms' relationship to syntax?

The canonical source on this, [The Jargon File](http://www.catb.org/%7Eesr/jargon/html/M/metasyntactic-variable.html), presents three different concepts (list-ified for clarity):

> Metasyntactic variables are so called because
>
> 1. They are variables in the metalanguage used to talk about programs etc.
> 2. They are variables whose values are often variables (as in usages like “the value of f(foo,bar) is the sum of foo and bar”).
> 3. However, it has been plausibly suggested that the real reason for the term “metasyntactic variable” is that it sounds good.

In addition, I've [personally made the argument](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/192145/is-there-a-word-which-means-whatever-you-want-it-to-mean-or-has-no-meaning/192146#comment400892_192146) that their meta-syntacticness arises from the fact that the same words can be used to stand in for *any* part of speech.

In any case, while (1) or some version of it is probably the first idea that would come to most people's minds, the fact that the Jargon File didn't stop there is telling, and I think finding the origins of the term will shed a lot of light here.

#### Non-software uses or origins

The Terry Pratchett answer above also got me thinking: do non-computer scientists use the term *metasyntactic variable*, in a non-software context? Are there people who use this term non-ironically, who are not familiar with its software sense?

I would be particularly interested in answers which show the term *pre-dates* its use in software. Given that "syntax" is really only studied by one other group, I wonder do linguists or syntacticians of natural languages³ use this term at all? Did they do so before, say, 1950?

---

¹ <sub>Interestingly, *foo* and *bar* have their own, detailed etymology, and no, it's not as straightforward as "arising from the WWII acronym FUBAR". See [RFC 3092](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3092) and the [canonical post about *foo* here on EL&U](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/34566/9001).</sub>

² <sub>I actually was forced to use only Google Books for the full term; for some reason, *metasyntactic variable* doesn't show up in nGram Viewer at all.</sub>

³ <sub>I once made the case that words like "thingy", "doodad", "whatshisface", etc are "metasyntactic variables", but [John Lawler says they're more properly termed "nonce forms"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/192145/is-there-a-word-which-means-whatever-you-want-it-to-mean-or-has-no-meaning/192146#comment471323_192146) by linguists.</sub>

<sub>**PS**: I know I've picked the low-hanging fruit here, with Google Books and Google nGram Viewer, but I would really still prefer scholastic, detailed answers. Speculation will just add noise. Though I'm also happy to accept first-hand accounts from people who lived through the 50s-60s-70s computer era (or very credible second-hand accounts).</sub>

Comment: Meta is used as a prefix in many disciplines to refer to talking about the content of the discipline rather than anything in it. So a metasyntax would be used as a syntax to make statements about some computer language 's syntax The most common one in linguistics (and teaching) is, of course, metalanguage which is used to make statements about an actual language or its use. I don't see how this metasyntactic variable is any different....a variable used in a metasyntax (in computing). This is all off the top of my head, but I believe it is accurate.

Comment: @Lambie Yes, that is sense #1 recorded by The Jargon File, but even they didn't commit to it as the canonical or even most plausible origin. That they didn't commit is the reason I ask!

Comment: But it follows the logic. I don't know its "history". Metalanguage is very common in linguistics and language teaching/learning or any discipline. Close to discourse. Sometimes, there isn't a canon. There is just the first time a term is used.

Comment: I understand, but I'm not asking about logic, I'm asking about history, because time and again, language has proven itself iredeemably illogical. As for "just the first time it's used", it looks and smells like a consciously constructed phrase, and given its (very likely) origins in computer science, among engineers who value precision and clarity above all else, I doubt it was just a nonce form made up on the spot. I think it was invented purposefully. Anyway, if and when we find that first use (or very early uses), we will know!

Comment: [metasyntax](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22metasyntax%22&biw=1134&bih=823&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F1800%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F1970&tbm=bks) seems to have surfaced in the 1960s. My guess would be that it was borrowed from German linguists, rather being a computer geek usage.

Comment: @FumbleFingers If you want to pull on that thread, it might make a great answer indeed. I would actually love to learn the term had linguistic origins, predating its use in software.

Comment: It is not a term used in linguistics. But like everything else, someone may have scooped it up. People do weird things these days; You use metalanguage (of many varieties, I might add)  to study natural language syntax. I personally don't see how it could be used in the study of natural languages. The meaning does not fit. There is no metasyntax for studying a  natural language, only metalanguages.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The author of that Aussie hit in your link states that he means "after the syntax". So, that is not way it it is used here metasyntax is used in programming.

Comment: Much more on *foo*: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/34566/9001

Comment: @Hugo Awesome! Didn't think to search for *foo* on EL&U itself. I'll add your answer there to footnote 1, alongside RFC 3092, which I see you also reference.

Comment: What answer are you looking for? Why is the huge amount of information you have found not satisfactory yet?

Comment: @Josh See the last section of my starter answer: I haven't found a bridge from *metasyntactic* to *metasyntatic variable*, nor do I know when the term was first applied to terms like *foo* and *bar*, nor do I have concrete proof that the terms actually evolved from Backus' *metalinguistic formulas*. In short, I need a canonical answer. I want to settle the etymology once and for all.

Comment: In case you  have not seen this yet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4868904/what-is-the-origin-of-foo-and-bar

Comment: Excellent discussion. Just by way of adding to the references. I thought RFC 3092 offered an interesting perspective on the relationship between foo and metasyntactic variables. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3092 (apologies, just saw this referenced before)

Answer (score 6):

#### Ingerman and Sattley 1960

I decided to pull on the thread of use of *metasyntactic* by Ingerman and Sattley in their November 1960 memo.

#### Knuth 1961

Searching for their names in relation to the language name *ALGOL* quickly revealed an abstract of a paper by Knuth titled [*ALGOL 60 confidential*](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=366573.366599), written June 1961, which uses the word *metalinguistic*:

> *The ALGOL 60 Report,* when first encountered, seems to describe a very complex language which will be difficult to learn. The “**metalinguistic formulae**” admirably serve the purpose of precisely specifying a language, but they are certainly not very readable for a beginner.

Following that lead and searching for the term "metalinguistic formulae" in relation to Knuth, we find *Development, Assessment, and Reengineering of Language Descriptions* by Alex Sellink and Chris Verhoef, undated but from its bibiliography no earlier than 1999:

> In his paper on the syntax and semantics of the proposed international algebraic language, Backus [2] writes: `*we shall need some metalinguistic conventions for characterizing various strings of symbols. To begin, we shall need metalinguistic formulae.*' Then he introduced using an example what is now widely known as the Backus-Naur Formalism.

#### Backus 1959

And the light begins to dawn. Backus-Naur Form is the famous notation for describing computer languages. That is, it is a *language* for describing languages: a metalanguage. Note that the ALGOL Bulletin where we found the earliest use of *metasyntactic* is in fact compiled by Naur, who co-created the Backus-Naur form.

So, chasing down Sellink and Verhoef's reference [2], we find Backus' *[The Syntax and Semantics of the Proposed International Algebraic Language of the Zurich ACM-GAMM Conference.](http://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/ALGOL/paper/Backus-Syntax_and_Semantics_of_Proposed_IAL.pdf/view)*, written 1959:

> Syntax of IAL
>
> In the description of IAL syntax which follows we shall
>   need some metalinguistic conventions for characterizing various
>   strings of symbols. To begin, we shall need **metalinguistic formulas**.
>   Their interpretation is best explained by an example:

This use of *metalinguistic formulas* was enthusiastically quoted by Knuth, by Sellink and Verhoef, by several other authors and papers I encountered in this search, and the very wording is emphasized in [the relevant Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form#cite_ref-Backus.1969_6-0).

Similarly, the Wikipedia article quotes Naur, two years later, in 1961:

> The meaning of **syntactic formula** may be further explained by saying that words enclosed in the brackets `< >`, like `<ab>`, denote classes whose members are sequences of basic symbols. Class designations of this kind are found in any description of a language. For describing ordinary natural languages designation like word, verb, noun, are used. Peter Naur (1961)."[A COURSE ON ALGOL PROGRAMMING](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1064049&CFID=648579078&CFTOKEN=25521706)". p. 5, Note 1. Retrieved 26 March 2015.

So it seems it was Backus' use of *metalinguistic* that galavanized and motivated its use in the early computer industry, and likely inspired the related word *metasyntactic* used by Ingerman and Sattley, who moved in the same circles.

#### From "metasyntactic" to "metasyntactic variables"

I haven't yet been able to hunt down the first use of "metasyntactic variable" as applied to terms like "foo" and "bar" but it now seems inescapable that it developed out of the use of *metalinguistic formulas* as coined by Backus in 1959.

This coinage was adopted in the ALGOL community in the 1960s, to grew to  the extent that the "variable" term was applied and understood more broadly in language design circles by no later than the late 1970s (as used by Galley and Pfister in the *MDL Language* book in the question; MDL was a derivative of LISP, another early programming language).

If I can find a more direct connection, or fill in a few more of the missing links, I will update this answer.

Comment: From [What is a Grammar?](https://web.cs.wpi.edu/~jshutt/adapt/grammar.html) ***Metasyntactic** values, in the sense I'm using here, are descriptive of syntax, as for example the nonterminals of a **Chomsky grammar**.* But I've never been a great fan of his ideas re "genetic encoding of universal grammar", and I more than suspect modern AI-based natural language processing with "non-biological" neural nets will increasingly undermine his thinking.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks, good find. However, that looks like it was written in 2011, long after the lines I'm trying to find were well-blurred. If you can find an earlier use of "meta-X" in relation to Chomsky, ideally the 50s or 60s, that would be a very helpful lead.

Comment: I haven't perhaps been assiduous in grasping *exactly* what "metasyntax" - or more specifically, "metasyntactic variable" means in the Algol context, but it looks to me like it's just what I would call a *parameter*, or *parameter list* if I needed to identify one (when pointing to it in the **Syntax;** definition line in a programming language reference, for example).

Comment: @FumbleFingers There are three terms, from three different contexts, here. There is "metasyntactic variables" (general use), "metalinguistic formulas" (as used by Backus in the BNF/IAL context), and "metasyntactic contexts" (as used by Ingerman in the ALGOL context). They all mean different things, but in a broad sense, yes, they're all parameters. The reason they're tagged as "meta" is because they're not parameters in functions of a programming language, but parameters for functions for *generating* a programming language, or describing one.

Answer (score 2):

With a hyphen, I first see "meta-syntactic variable" being used in  [Software 71: proceedings of a conference sponsored by Software World and held at the University of Kent at Canterbury](https://books.google.com/books?id=RdlWAAAAMAAJ&q=%22meta%20syntactic%22&dq=%22meta%20syntactic%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwidlorXgMfSAhWF7yYKHZbsBwoQ6AEIMDAE), July 1971:

> Here 'TYPE' and "MODE" are meta-syntactic variables such as used in the definition of ALGOL 68 [reference 3].
>
> R3 TYPE--> procedure | data-structure

Where reference 3 is VAN WYNGAARDEN, A., MAILLOUX, B.J. , PECK, J.E.L., and KOSTER, C.H.A., '[Draft report on the algorithmic language ALGOL 68](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1064073)', Amsterdam Mathematisch Centrum.

Without a hyphen "metasyntactic variable" is used in the May 1972 thesis of Michael Kelly Donegan, [CODE GENERATION FOR NEW ON THE
RICE RESEARCH COMPUTER](https://scholarship.rice.edu/bitstream/handle/1911/89312/RICE0350.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y).  The word "NEW" is underlined in the title and refers to the computer language NEW.

> VARIABLE assignation: reference destination,
>   becomes symbol, value source.
>
> The semantic interpretation of the assignation is embodied
>   in the syntax by asserting that the destination is to be
>   elaborated in reference mode and the source in value mode.
>   VARIABLE is a metasyntactic variable whose rule is
>
> VARIABLE: reference; value.
>
> This asserts, in the case of assignations, that the value of
>   an assignation may have two interpretations. The value in
>   reference mode is the value of the destination, while in
>   value mode it is the value of the source.

The plural form "metasyntactic variables" is used in the 1975 book [The structure and design of programming languages](https://books.google.com/books?id=IdEmAAAAMAAJ&q=%22metasyntactic%20variables%22&dq=%22metasyntactic%20variables%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiV1NW89brSAhUKySYKHfrjBpsQ6AEIHjAB)

The term "syntactic variable" had been in use since about 1950 in the symbolic logic and computer fields.

See for example the 1959 [Journal of the Association for Computing Machinery](https://books.google.com/books?id=X9dPAAAAYAAJ&q=%22Note%20that%20the%20symbols%20pi,%20pi,%20etc.%20occur%20here%20as%20syntactic%20variables%22&dq=%22Note%20that%20the%20symbols%20pi,%20pi,%20etc.%20occur%20here%20as%20syntactic%20variables%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiWzIq9gLvSAhVDRSYKHWZlDxsQ6AEIGjAA) which has a footnote:

> Note that the symbols p1, p2, etc. occur here as "syntactic variables." That is, they stand for expressions made up of our symbols.

Comment: Nicely nicely found. I already upvoted you. I'm particularly pleased with your find of the earlier "syntactic variables".

Comment: Nice edit! Now since your '71 reference cites ALGOL 68, you might chase that down to find how the phrase was defined in that paper. I think we're on the home stretch here!

Comment: @DanBron The reference is VAN WYNGAARDEN, A., MAILLOUX, B.J. , PECK, J.E.L., and KOSTER, C.H.A., 'Draft report on the algorithmic language ALGOL 68', Amsterdam Mathematisch Centrum. http://www.eah-jena.de/~kleine/history/languages/Algol68-Report.pdf

Comment: I haven't read the PDF yet: does it define *metasyntactic variable*? Does it cite an even earlier source on that topic?

Comment: @DanBron I haven't looked at it much yet, over 100 pages.  It seems to use tons of "meta" words but I don't see "metasyntactic variable" specifically so far.

Comment: @DanBron This is a more-official link http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1064073

Comment: @DanBron It has a section "Syntax of the Metalanguage" and uses terms "metanotation" and "metaproduction" dozens of times, but not "metasyntactic".

Comment: Hmm, too bad, I'll take a look later and see what I can find. If anything I'll leave a comment here and you can incorporate into your answer as you see fit. Thank you for all your hard work here. I'm impressed you were able to dig up these earlier cites, with Google being so unhelpful. The +500 is already yours, I just need to wait til the last day, in good faith.

Comment: @DanBron There is also an August 1973 use of "meta-syntactic variables" here: https://books.google.com/books?id=wXhFAAAAYAAJ&q=%22meta+syntactic+variables%22&dq=%22meta+syntactic+variables%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiRnaicjMfSAhVDJCYKHTCaBf8Q6AEIJDAC Third International Joint conference on Artificial Intelligence.

Comment: Turns out today *is* the last day for the bounty. Congratulations, and thank you. You've done a lot of great work.